# Match two RDDs [String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I try to match two RDD's:
RDD1 contains a huge amount of words [String] and RDD2 contains city names [String].

I want to return a RDD with the elements from RDD1 that are in RDD2.
Something like the opposite to `subtract`.

Afterwards I want to count the occurrence of each remaining word, but that won't be a problem.

thank you

Comment: Do you mean `intersection`?

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but from "I want to count the occurrence of each remaining word" I made conclusion, that number of each string duplicates  matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to return an RDD with the elements from RDD1 that are in RDD2

If I got you right:

```
rdd1.subtract(rdd2.subtract(rdd1))
```

Note the difference between this code and `intersection`:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq("a", "a", "b", "c"))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq("a", "c", "d"))
val diff = rdd1.subtract(rdd2)
rdd1.subtract(diff).collect()
res0: Array[String] = Array(a, a, c)
rdd1.intersection(rdd2).collect()
res1: Array[String] = Array(a, c)
```

So, if your first RDD contains duplicates, and your goal is to take into account that duplicates, your may prefer double `subtract` solution. Otherwise, `intersection` fits well.

Comment: exactly, dublicates matter for us, that's why we can't use distinct. Tahnk you very much :) you just made three students really happy

Comment: we just haven't thought of an inner transformation. :)